# Knapsack Problem for Fixed weight and Fixed price

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Is the knapsack problem for a target weight, let's say 1000 for example, and a target price, let's say 10000, still an NPC problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. If you have $n$ items, and a capacity of $W$, there is a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm using dynamic programming that runs in $O(Wn)$ time. Thus, for any constant weight, we can solve the Knapsack problem in linear time.